# query_posts with meta_value

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, array, meta-value, parameter

I have category **'news'** `http://localhost/foldername/news`, for each **'news'** posts I have custom field called **'years'** and is set up as a Text Field. I have 2 values assigned n different posts **'2013'** and **'2014'**.

What I'm trying to do first to show only **2014** posts in **'news'** category `http://localhost/foldername/news` and second to pass url parameter so if I want to show **'2013'** to use the following `http://localhost/foldername/news/?years=2013`

I have selected Attribute so user will select which year posts to show but as default will show 2014 posts

```
 <select>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
```

For the first I found the following solution to show only **'2014'** posts in **'news'** `http://localhost/foldername/news`:

```
    $args= array(   
    'meta_key' => 'years',
    'meta_value' => '2014',
    );
   query_posts($args);
```

Now my big problem is that I pass the parameter to show **'2013'** posts but is not working

Tried something like this:

```
function wpse129223_custom_meta_query( $query ) {

    // If not on the main query, or on an admin page, bail here
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || is_admin() ) {
    return;
}

// If 'type' isn't being passed as a query string, bail here
if ( empty( $_GET['years'] ) ) {
    return;
}

// Get the existing meta query, cast as array
$meta_query = (array) $query->get('meta_query');

    // Convert 'type' into an array of types
    $types = explode( ',', $_GET['years'] );

    // Ensure that types aren't empty
    if ( is_array( $types ) && ! empty( $types ) ) {

        // Build a meta query for this type
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'years',
            'value'   => $types,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );

        // Update the meta query
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    } 

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse129223_custom_meta_query' );
```

But every time I go to `http://localhost/foldername/news/?years=2013` still shows me **'2014'** posts

Comment: Have you still got the `query_posts($args);` running? If so remove that. Then in your `pre_get_posts` do a check for `is_category( 'news' )` at the top. Then set the default years to "2014" by removing the check on `empty( $_GET...` and using `$types = explode( ',', empty( $_GET['years'] ) ? "2014" : $_GET['years'] );`

Comment: @bonger Please add your comment as an answer. This is **useful** info that will just rot and die in comments, it deserves to be in an answer ;-).

Comment: @bonger Agree with Pieter Goosen, will appreciate if you post it as an answer

Comment: Wilco.........!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, just use `pre_get_posts` filter (no `query_posts()`) very much as you have it with a few adjustments, eg test for `$query->is_category( 'news' )` so that it only runs on news queries, and set the default to "2014" rather than bailing on no `$_GET`, eg

```
function wpse129223_custom_meta_query( $query ) {

    // If not on the main query, or on an admin page, bail here
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || is_admin() || ! $query->is_category( 'news' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the existing meta query, cast as array
    $meta_query = (array) $query->get('meta_query');

    // Convert 'type' into an array of types
    $types = explode( ',', empty( $_GET['years'] ) ? '2014' : $_GET['years'] );

    // Ensure that types aren't empty
    if ( is_array( $types ) && ! empty( $types ) ) {

        // Build a meta query for this type
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'years',
            'value'   => $types,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );

        // Update the meta query
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    } 

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse129223_custom_meta_query' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Also If I want to add more than one category to show only 2014 what I need to change tried something like this but didnt work `$query->is_category( 'news' , 'liveleak' )`

Comment: Good stuff! If you put them in an array it should work, `$query->is_category( array( 'news' , 'livelea' ) )`